# move columns from a table to its parent

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

In postgresql 9.1, I've *tableB* inheriting from *tableA*.

There are some columns in *tableB*, and no column in *tableA*.

I want to move columns from tableB to *tableA* without dumping and reimporting rows from *TableB*… is it possible ? (I precise I have no rows at all directly in *tableA*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the parent table and add the same columns as what exists in the child table(s). Any columns that *already* exist in the child tables with the same data type will not propagate to the children, but any columns that you create in the parent that do not already exist in the child *will* get created in the child tables.

```
-- Create parent table "p"
create table p();

-- Create child table "c"
create table c (id int, val text, val2 text) inherits (p);

-- Add the columns to the parent
-- which already exist in the child table "c".
alter table p add val text;
alter table p add val2 text;

-- Add a column that does not exist in table "c"
alter table p add val_xxx bigint;


\d p
       Table "public.p"
 Column  |  Type  | Modifiers 
---------+--------+-----------
 val     | text   | 
 val2    | text   | 
 val_xxx | bigint | 
Number of child tables: 1 (Use \d+ to list them.)
```

Edited to show the results of follow-up question about what happens to the row(s) in the inherited tables if one of the columns is removed from the parent and child table.

```
begin;
-- Drop the "val" column from the parent table
alter table p drop column val; 

-- The "val" colum no longer exists in the parent table.
select * from only p;
 val2 | val_xxx 
------+---------
(0 rows)

-- The "val" column still exists in the inherited (child) table
select * from c;
 id | val | val2 | val_xxx 
----+-----+------+---------
  1 | aaa | bbb  |     999

-- Drop the column from the inherited (child) table
alter table c drop column val;

-- The "val" column no longer exists in the child table
select * from c;
 id | val2 | val_xxx 
----+------+---------
  1 | bbb  |     999

rollback;
```

Comment: Thanks @bma, I'll try to mock it…
I still have a question : after your sample, if i delete column c.val, what will happen to rows from c ? (since column val still exists from p, I'd expect these rows to remain untouched… this is the crucial point in my question…)

Comment: Does the section I just added demonstrating dropping a column help answer your question about what happens to the existing rows? Answer: the rows remain nearly unchanged except the column you dropped will no longer show in the table.